# How to create a scatter plot for two data classes with pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have two sets of data, `x` and `y` as ints.  I need to plot both of these data points using `matplotlib.pyplot.scatter`.  I also need to plot the first category `y == 0` in one color and the second, `y == 1` in a different color.

I've looked at the documentation for the scatter function, but I don't understand how to do all of this in one plot.

Sample data:

```
2.897534798034255,0.872359037956732,1
1.234850239781278,-0.293047584301112,1
0.238575209753427,0.129572680572429,0
-0.109757648021958,0.484048547480385,1
1.109735783200013,-0.002785328902198,0
1.572803975652908,0.098547849368397,0
```

x and y are defined as:

```
x = data[:, [0, 1]]
y = data[:, -1].astype(int)
```

Size of x is 2000, size of y is 1000

My attempt:

```
pl.scatter(x, y==0, s=3, c='r')
pl.scatter(x, y==1, s=3, c='b')
pl.show()
```

Comment: To improve your question, you could provide your data as a numpy array (see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).

Comment: In short, write the shortest code that fully shows a problem and post it here. Include all imports etc. and post it here in full. Should be <10 lines in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.array([[2.897534798034255,0.872359037956732,1],
                 [1.234850239781278,-0.293047584301112,1],
                 [0.238575209753427,0.129572680572429,0],
                 [-0.109757648021958,0.484048547480385,1],
                 [1.109735783200013,-0.002785328902198,0],
                 [1.572803975652908,0.098547849368397,0]])

x = data[:, [0, 1]]
y = data[:, -1].astype(int)

plt.scatter(x[:,0][y==0], x[:,1][y==0], s=3, c='r')
plt.scatter(x[:,0][y==1], x[:,1][y==1], s=3, c='b')
plt.show()
```

Although this is perhaps more readable:

```
x1 = data[:, 0]
x2 = data[:, 1]
y = data[:, -1].astype(int)

plt.scatter(x1[y==0], x2[y==0], s=3, c='r')
plt.scatter(x1[y==1], x2[y==1], s=3, c='b')
```

Output:

[image: Scatterplot]

Answer (score 3):

`pyplot.scatter()` accepts a list of colors, hence:

```py
c = ['r' if yy==0 else 'b' for yy in y]
plt.scatter(x, y, c=c)
```

In your code, `y==0` produces a mask that has only `True` and `False` values, not `y` values to be plotted. If `x` and `y` are numpy arrays, you can do:

```py
mask = (y == 0)
plt.scatter(x[mask], y[mask], c='r')
mask = (y == 1)
plt.scatter(x[mask], y[mask], c='b')
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to extract `x` and `y` first and filter later. Given that you have a lot of data and not many categories, `plt.plot` with markers should also be faster than `plt.scatter`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.asarray([[2.897534798034255,0.872359037956732,1],
                     [1.234850239781278,-0.293047584301112,1],
                     [0.238575209753427,0.129572680572429,0],
                     [-0.109757648021958,0.484048547480385,1],
                     [1.109735783200013,-0.002785328902198,0],
                     [1.572803975652908,0.098547849368397,0]])

colors = ["blue", "red", "green"]
labels = ["A", "B", "C"]

for i, c, l in zip(np.unique(data[:, 2]), colors, labels):   
    plt.plot(data[data[:, 2]==i][:, 0], data[data[:, 2]==i][:, 1], 
             marker="o", markersize=7, ls="None", color=c, 
             label=f"The letter {l} represents category {int(i)}")

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]